# Website sometimes renders as text instead of html

Tags: html, apache, tomcat, grails

I'm facing this issue when our website sometimes displays the actual HTML instead of rendering the HTML. And if you refresh the page it works fine.

So at times it displays HTML like below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>
 <head>...</head>
 <body><p>hello world</p></body>
</html>
```

And if you refresh it works fine. Happens randomly on different pages. I'm not sure what is causing the issue thats why have added tags for different tech we are using.

Comment: Does this happen on multiple systems? On other browsers? Have you cleared the cache? Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Are you sure that the correct content type header is sent back to browser? You can debug this using Network tab in any Inspector.

Comment: Yes it happens with multiple users on different browsers in different locations ... no I'm not behind a proxy.

Comment: @KristianVitozev content type is also correct text/html;charset=utf-8

Comment: Well, you can try to see if there are any differences in responses when browser rendere page correctly and when it's not rendered correctly. Play with "Network" tab of your inspector and write a comment if you notice something strange.